# Is there a way to add a width at which this canvas will stop resizing?

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I want to draw a bracket on my canvas. That much I can do. The issue is that when the window gets small enough the proportions of the bracket go all out of whack and it starts to move down. I tried add an if statement (in the code below) to stop it from redrawing at 960px across, but it has not seemed to have any effect. As well as adding a min-width property to the canvas. Unfortunately, neither of those did the trick. If you open the fiddle and resize the "results" window to be skinny you can see the effect that I am talking about. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
<canvas id="c" style= "position: absolute; left:0px; top:0px; 
background-color:#646464; min-width: 960px;">
</canvas>

<script>
(function(){
    var htmlCanvas = document.getElementById("c"), context = htmlCanvas.getContext("2d");
    initialize();

    function initialize(){
        window.addEventListener('resize', drawBracket, false);
        drawBracket();      
    }

    function drawBracket(){
    var a = 375
    if(window.innerWidth > 960){ 
        var spreadEnd = (window.innerWidth - window.innerWidth/1.5)
    }
    else{
        var spreadEnd = 320 
    }
    context.beginPath()
    context.moveTo(0, a)
    context.lineTo(spreadEnd, a)
    context.lineTo(spreadEnd, a + 120)
    context.lineTo(spreadEnd + 40, a + 120) 
    context.moveTo(spreadEnd, a + 120)
    context.lineTo(spreadEnd, a - 120)  
    context.lineTo(spreadEnd + 40, a - 120)
    context.stroke()    
    context.closePath()
    }

})();

</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dpfba47j/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are changing the width/height of the canvas on every window resize.

```
    function resizeCanvas() {
       htmlCanvas.width = window.innerWidth;
       htmlCanvas.height = window.innerHeight;
       redraw();
    }
```

add a conditional in here, where if the window width is less than or equal to 960, set the width to 960.

```
    function resizeCanvas() {
        if ( window.innerWidth <= 960 ) {
          htmlCanvas.width = 960;
          htmlCanvas.height = // whatever you want
        } else {
          htmlCanvas.width = window.innerWidth;
          htmlCanvas.height = window.innerHeight;
        }
        redraw();
    }
```

Comment: I would suggest `Math.min(window.innerWidth, 960)`

Comment: Ah, genius. That worked. My if statement placement is clearly not quite up to par yet. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. The suggestion from DJDavid could help reduce amount of code as well, `Math.min(option1, option2)` will return the smaller of the two options.